# графика qgraphicsscene::addellipse

Tags: c++, qt, графика

Как менять в addEllipse только параметр QBrush
Отрефакторил:

```
scene2->addEllipse(100, 395, radius1, radius1, QPen(Qt::black), QBrush(Qt::gray));
    if(link2 == 0) 
       scene2->addEllipse(100, 395, radius1, radius1, QPen(Qt::black), QBrush(Qt::red));
    if(link2 == 1) 
       scene2->addEllipse(100, 395, radius1, radius1, QPen(Qt::black), QBrush(Qt::green));
```

link2 изменяется по таймеру

Answer (score 0):

Есть функция такая **setBrush()**, туда в параметры передается **QBrush** - объекты **QBrush** обычно просто цвета, поскольку вы сказали про **QTimer** вот как это будет выглядеть в вашем варианте.

Я не знаю, насколько хорошо вы знаете плюсы, но это буквально первые страницы документации, но Qt-шная документация не дублирует некоторые функции во все разделы, поэтому приходится иногда кликать по зеленому названия там где Inheritance и искать в классе родителе функции, которые нужны главное чтобы тип public или protected был. [image: Класс с кружочками]

Я отнаследовался от класса **QGraphicsEllipseItem**, чтобы получить функции, которые находятся в нем и также сперва отнаследовался от QObject, потому что **QGraphicsItem** являющийся базовым для QGraphicsEllipseItem не наследуется от **QObject**, поэтому для того чтобы в будущем я мог создавать слоты и сигналы, то я наследуюсь от **QObject** и прописываю команду **Q_OBJECT** для мета-объектного компилятора.

[image: Класс родитель класса эллипса, с функцией setBrush() внутри]

Вот вам полностью рабочий вариант:

Хэдер:

```
#include <QGraphicsEllipseItem>
#include <QBrush>
#include <QPen>
#include <QTimer>

class CustomEllipse : public QObject, public QGraphicsEllipseItem{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    CustomEllipse(){
        this->setRect(QRectF(0, 0, 100, 395));
        this->setPen(QPen(Qt::black));
        QTimer* timer = new QTimer();
        connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(madeNewColor()));
        timer->start(1000);
    }

public slots:
    void madeNewColor(){
        time++;
        if((time % 2) == 0)
            this->setBrush(Qt::green);
        else
            this->setBrush(Qt::yellow);
    }
private:
    int time = 0;
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, 600, 600);

    CustomEllipse* ellipse = new CustomEllipse();
    scene->addItem(ellipse);

    QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView();
    view->setSceneRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
    view->setScene(scene);

    view->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Итог, каждую секунду меняется цвет:[image: Зеленый]

[image: Желтый]

Comment: Есть команда Q_UNUSED, но она чисто чтобы в Qt выключить подсветку желтую для каких-нибудь QWidget* parent = 0, а так отказаться заполнять функции полностью нельзя, но можно переопределять классы и писать свои функции с вызовом внутренних.

Comment: Не читайте книги, не смотрите курсы, читайте документацию. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractgraphicsshapeitem.html

Comment: Не вздумайте также в Qt создавать классы внутри main.cpp, потому что если в них будет Q_OBJECT, то метаобъектный компилятор их просто не достанет и свои классы всегда должны быть раскиданы по хэдерам минимум.